# What is the DBSCH command being passed to CartoDB's invalidation service?

Tags: carto

CartoDB's PostgreSQL extension (`cartodb-postgresql`) has a function defined here:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/blob/2e665a56b4a7dbc3bd8e3d91ac18b52bb932663c/scripts-available/CDB_GhostTables.sql#L2-L50

which includes the instantiation of a Redis python client (line 32). Then a call is made to that client (line 41) which looks like this:

```
client.execute_command('DBSCH', db_name, username, event_name)
```

`DBSCH` is not a Redis command, and I cannot find any documentation of it elsewhere in the CartoDB repositories.

**Does anyone know where to find the source of that command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the developer directly and got an answer: it's a custom Redis command, and the source is stored in a private repository.

If you look at this diff in the `cartodb-postgresql` repository, it would appear that the command is replacing a direct addition of a job to the Resque queue in Redis:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/commit/5f154a585910f4de5df08c1287d0fd5e02287f78#diff-e197cbbeb07315bf1df8566b72b43f59L32

The developer said the custom command can be worked around, though it wasn't clear if that meant overwriting the code or that there was an alternate execution path that simply avoids it.